# I'm getting an error message about packages that I'm not even using upon building with testng

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I'm trying to build a regression suite using Intellij and TestNG, not sure why this is happening. When I try to run it I get these:

[image]

My file structure is just:

```
AutoSuite/
|-.idea/
|- out/
|- src/
|-- com/
|--- site/
|------ data/
|--------- urlData.java
|------ homepage/
|--------- Homepage.java
|- tst/
|-- com/
|--- site/
|------ homepage/
|--------- HomepageTest.java
|- AutoSuite.iml
|- External Libraries/
```

The code inside the java files is as follows:

homepage.java
    package com.site.homepage;

```
public class Homepage {

    public String siteTitle() {
        return "site.com/";
    }

}
```

urlData.java

```
package com.site.data;

public class urlData {

    private static String DEV_WEB = "site.com/";

    public String returnPROD(){ return DEV_WEB; }
}
```

HomePageTest.java

```
package com.site.homepage;

import com.site.homepage.Homepage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class HomepageTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    Homepage homepage;
    String titleTag;

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void initStringsAndObjects() {
        homepage = new Homepage();
        titleTag = "Site title tag";
    }

    @Test (priority = 1, groups={"Layout"})
    public void testSiteTitle() {
        driver.get(homepage.siteTitle()); 
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals(titleTag)); 
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void cleanup() {
        titleTag = null;
        homepage = null;
    }
}
```

I thought maybe I needed a testng.xml file at under `AutoSuite/` but even after adding it under `Edit Configuration > Suite > testng.xml` I get the error. So I removed it.

Then I made sure I had testng in the dependencies it by selecting the file under `Project Preferences > Modules > Dependencies` and it's there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using selenium, which has its own dependencies.
To fix your missing dependencies you will either have to use a build system like Maven or Gradle that will handle these things for you, or use a selenium version with all dependencies included (called standalone):
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: I thought I had this handled? I have it under dependencies in `Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies` and then have it directly to `~/selenium-java-3.11.0` Scope "test". Should it be pointing to another directory?

Comment: In the `selenium-java` folder should be a `libs` folder with a few jars. Try add that to the dependencies